# Cant find bean that is clearly defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have this configuration class in two different kotlin projects.

In one it works just fine. In the other one, I get an error and I am asked to make the class open, and when I run the program, the bean cannot be found.

I am really confused as the same configuration seems to be working fine in a different project. Could you please suggest a way that would allow me to avoid making the class open, as I dont see the reason for doing so since in the other project I did not have to, or a reason why the bean cannot be found?

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value = ["com.bank.manager"])
@PropertySources(PropertySource("classpath:application.yml"),
                 PropertySource(value = ["file:\${bank.target.config}"]))
class BankInstanceConfig(@Autowired private val env: Environment) {

    @Bean fun bankInstance(): List<String> {
        return env.getRequiredProperty("bank-instance").toString().split("#")
    }
}
```

Then on class level I define the bean like this:

```
@Service
class BankDiscoveryServiceImpl(@Autowired bankInstance: BankInstanceConfig) {}
```

Comment: Are you using the [all-open](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#all-open-compiler-plugin) compiler plug-in?

Comment: @gidds most likely he is using `all-open` or [spring-support](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#spring-support) in one project, and not in the other. @C96 A Spring `@Configuration` class needs to be extendable and there is no way around that, the Kotlin class needs to be open, since it is final by default.